# Converging to $C_{0} (\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I got came to know a result stating that: the uniform closure of $C_{c} ^ \infty (\mathbb R)$ is $C_{0} (\mathbb R)$.

Now, what I have thought that: to prove $C_{0} (\mathbb R)$ is the closure of $C_{c} ^ \infty (\mathbb R)$ we have to find out a sequence of functions from $C_{c} ^ \infty (\mathbb R)$ which converges to an arbitrarily chosen function $C_{0} (\mathbb R)$ . Intuitively I could manage to go that much only... Please show me a rigorous proof!

Comment: Have you seen convolutions and approximate identities (which are also sometimes called mollifiers)? These give an easy way to prove that each function in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is the uniform limit of functions in $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}).$ Also, you still have something more to prove. You must also show that the uniform limit of a Cauchy sequence in $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is in $C_0(\mathbb{R}).$ Can you do that?

Comment: I am studying Functional Analysis on my own.... I have come across the "molifiers" .... But couldn't extract anything from that!! That's why I posed the questn here.

Comment: You can also use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem here: $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is a subalgebra of functions which separates points in $\mathbb R,$ so it is dense in $C_0(\mathbb R).$

Comment: @user92360 You have to mention the topology in which you wish to seek the closure. For e.g. closure in $L^p$ norm would be $ L^p(\mathbb{R}) $, for $1\leq p < \infty$, you probably are looking for the $ L^\infty$ case. But in all of these, main idea is to choose your function and smoothen it by mollyfing, then compactify it by cutoff functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define continuous functions $h_n$ with values in $[0,1]$ which are $1$ on $[-n.n]$, $0$ outside $[-n-1,n+1]$ (and e.g. affin on the two remaining intervals). Check that $h_nf \to f$ uniformly for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$.